# Post method does not display view

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have a project to work with `json` and `ajax`. I have a `GET` method which returns `ingest.html` template. After that data from view goes to `POST` method where data saves in database and then method returns different view. So, I got data to go to that `POST` method, it was saved in database but post method did not display the view, it stayed on the same page. What am I doing wrong?

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class IngestController {

@Autowired
private IngestService ingestService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/ingest")
public String ingestForm(){
    return "/resources/html/ingest.html";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/ingest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createIngest(@RequestBody IngestMedia ingestMedia){

    ingestService.createIngest(ingestMedia);
    return "/resources/html/result.html";
}
```

**servlet.xml:**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.controllers">
</context:component-scan>
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

**index.html:**

```html
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
      title = $("#title").val();
      mediaType = $("#mediaType").val();
      employeeId = $("#employeeId").val();
      var ingestMedia = {
        "title": title,
        "mediaType": mediaType,
        "employeeId": employeeId
      }
      createIngestRecord(ingestMedia);
    });
  });

  function createIngestRecord(ingestMedia) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: "/ingest",
      data: JSON.stringify(ingestMedia), // Note it is important
      success: function(data) {
        alert("Done");
      }
    });
  }
</script>

<body>
  <h1> Ingest </h1>
  Title<br>
  <input type="text" id="title"><br> MediaType
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="mediaType"><br> Employee Id<br>
  <input type="text" id="employeeId"><br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="button" value="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the data saved in database? You are requesting POST via AJAX call. And AJAX request will never render any page. It just send request and receive response from server.

Comment: If you want to **render / redirect or show pages** from controller then you shouldn't use ajax call. If you want to keep your view [html/jsp page] same then you need to manipulate data received from server-- *here your can do it with ajax*. So choice is yours.

Comment: @Zico Yes, data is saved in database.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Can you explain this in more details, please

Comment: Did you read ever anything about `ajax` call ? @Alexey

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Now I did, thank you! :) I did not know, that I can't return view  from controller using ajax call.